# Clarification on Bona's combinatorics question on Pg 46: drawing $5$ numbers out of a set of $90$ numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, soft-question

This is a question from A Walk Through Combinatorics by Bona pg 46. I think the question is worded a little bit confusingly. Can anyone help me through this question?

---

**Question:**

Assume that we play a lottery game where five numbers
are drawn out of $\{1, \ldots, 90\}$, but the numbers drawn are put back into the
basket right after being selected.

To win the jackpot, one must have played
the same multiset of numbers as the one drawn (regardless of the order in
which the numbers were drawn). How many lottery tickets do we have to
buy to make sure that we win the jackpot?

---

I am stuck on the phrase: "one must have played the same multiset of numbers as the one drawn". Is there a better way to phrase this question?

Also, why isn't the answer of this question simply $90^5$, since we are putting back the number after it is being drawn, so each drawn has $90$ possible choices.

Comment: Hint: The number of winning combinations is the number of solutions in non-negative integers of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{90}=5$.

Comment: Since drawing "1,2,1,1,1" is the same as drawing "2,1,1,1,1", it can't be all of $90^5$.

Comment: The order of the numbers in a multiset is irrelevant.  That's why the answer is not $90^5$.

Comment: *Stars and bars* will help you find the right binomial coefficient